# Writing external files dir still needs permission

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am using [`Context.getExternalFilesDir()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)) to store some files. According to the JavaDoc, i do not need any permissions to write these files:

> Starting in KITKAT, no permissions are required to read or write to
>   the returned path; it's always accessible to the calling app.

However, i got crash reports from a Huawei device, that it could not write to this file due to missing permission:

```
/storage/sdcard1/Android/data/<packagename>/files/Pictures/profile_1483988472572.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

What can i do? Obviously it would be a bad thing to ask for permissions although i do not need it expect on this (buggy ?) device.

Comment: are you sure that the crash is on kitkat or above?

Comment: `...../files/Pictures/.....` Well you should have started to tell if you could create that `Pictures`.directory. Now could you?.` Does it exist now?  It does not make much sense to try to write a file to a non existing directory.

Comment: @Manza yes, i checked the OS version on fabric.

Comment: @greenapps i can create the directory on my devices and on the emulator. I do not know what happens on those devices where crashes are happening, because the crashes are reported remotely in Fabric.

Comment: It is peculiar that you would be able to create a directory but not a file in it. Hard to believe.

Comment: @greenapps you completely misunderstood what i wrote. Everything works fine on my devices, the crashes are coming from Crashlytics (Fabric), so i do not know what happens on those certain remote devices.

Answer (score -1):

Put your code into AndroidManifest.xml

"uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE""

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Please read the question again. The point is that this permission is not needed on Kitkat for `Context.getExternalFilesDir()` .